# How to calculate the solubility of AgCl in a MgSO₄ solution?

Tags: physical-chemistry, solubility

The solubility product of $\ce{AgCl}$ in water is given as $1.8\cdot10^{-10}$
Determine the solubility of $\ce{AgCl}$ in pure water and in a $0.25~\mathrm{M}$ $\ce{MgSO4}$ solution.

I solve to the $K_\mathrm{{sp}}$ and got $1.34\cdot10^{-10}$
for Part B I was told to use the activity and am not sure if I did it right,
my new $K_\mathrm{{sp}}$ turn out to be $1.123\cdot10^{11}$
could someone help me with part B?

Comment: On Chemistry StackExchange some personal effort on [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142) questions needs to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

In pure water, as you calculated, for the reaction
$\ce{AgCl -> Ag+ + Cl-}$ with $K_\mathrm{sp} = 1.8\cdot10^{-10}$
 the concentration of $\ce{Ag+}$, i.e. $\ce{[Ag+]}$ will be $1.34\cdot10^{-5}~\mathrm{M}$.

In a solution of $0.25~\mathrm{M}$ $\ce{MgSO4}$ (which dissociates almost completely), there's an additional equilibrium here:
$\ce{Ag2SO4 -> 2Ag+ + SO4^2-}$ with [$K_\mathrm{sp} = 1.4\cdot10^{-5}$](http://bilbo.chm.uri.edu/CHM112/tables/KspTable.htm)

Looking at the $K_\mathrm{sp}$ of both the reactions, we can see that $\ce{AgCl}$, having the lesser solubility, decides the $\ce{[Ag+]}$. Here we can even check if the concentration of $\ce{[Ag+]} = 1.34\cdot10^{-5}~\mathrm{M}$ and $\ce{[SO4^{2-}]} = 0.25~\mathrm{M}$ exceeds the solubility limit of $\ce{Ag2SO4}$. It doesn't. 
$(1.34\cdot10^{-5})^2 \cdot 0.25 = 4.5\cdot10^{-11} < (K_\mathrm{sp})_{\ce{Ag2SO4}}$

The final composition of the solution will be $\ce{[Ag+]} = 1.34\cdot10^{-5}~\mathrm{M}$, $\ce{[Cl- ]} = 1.34\cdot10^{-5}~\mathrm{M}$, $\ce{[Mg^2+]} = 0.25~\mathrm{M}$ and $\ce{[SO4^2- ]} = 0.25~\mathrm{M}$.

In conclusion, the $\ce{[Ag+]}$ is the same for both the cases.

Comment: Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$. Over excessive usage of HTML is not necessary, there are more tools described in the [help].